# Transform unconstrained optimization problems into constrained ones?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization, convex-optimization

I want to formally show that the following minimization problem
$$
\min_\theta||\max(0,f_1(\theta)),...,\max(0,f_n(\theta))||^2
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\min_{\beta, \{w_i \}^{n}_{i=1}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2 \text{ s.t. } f_i(\theta)\leq w_i
 \text{ and } w_i \geq 0 \text{ } \forall i 
$$
where $f_i (\theta):\Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Could you help me?

Comment: Ok, but in this case are the two problems equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta,w$ solve 
$$
\min \sum w_i^2 \quad s.t. \quad f_i(\theta)\le w_i, \ w_i \ge 0.
$$
Th constraints are equivalent to $w_i \ge \max(f_i(\theta),0)$.
Then it follows that 
$$
w_i = \max(0,f_i(\theta)).
$$
If not then $w_i$ could be reduced to make $\sum w_i^2$ smaller without violating the constraints.

Hence both problems are equivalent.